# Number of spatial arrangements of tetrasubstituted biphenyl

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, isomers

[image: 2-bromo-2'-(1-chloroethyl)-6'-iodo-6-(prop-1-en-1-yl)-1,1'-biphenyl]

According to my book 2-bromo-2'-(1-chloroethyl)-6'-iodo-6-(prop-1-en-1-yl)-1,1'-biphenyl has eight possible spatial arrangements. How can this be so? I can think of only four – left two groups being planar with right two groups up-down and down-up, and vice versa.
For this configuration of I and $\ce{CHClCH3}$ I can think of four, for I and $\ce{CHClCH3}$ interchanged I can think of four more, but that is not the same molecule and is just a configurational isomer.

Comment: There is a cis/trans thing in one substituent and a chiral center in another.

Comment: @IvanNeretin will that be so when the substituents are planar or up/down? I'm a bit confused about the planar part actually.

Comment: Roughly speaking, the rings are perpendicular to each other. You may think that one is horizontal (I guess that's what you mean by planar) and another is up/down, or vice versa; it is all the same.

Comment: Double bond isomerism is a type of stereoisomerism as well, and certainly has to do with the spatial arrangement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three independent stereogenic centers or elements in this molecule,

- chiral carbon atom of the chloroethyl group,
- double bond of the propenyl group,
- axis of the substituted biphenyl with bulky substituents at 2,2′,6,6′ positions.

Each of them has two configurations. It means that the total number of stereoisomers is 2<sup>3</sup> = 8. (No one of them is symmetrical and cannot be superimposed with its mirror image, no one can be superimposed with any other one.)

[image: Fig. 1: Formulas I-VIII]

1. (1*M*)-2-bromo-2′-[(1*R*)-1-chloroethyl]-6′-iodo-6-[(1*Z*)-prop-1-en-1-yl]-1,1′-biphenyl
2. (1*M*)-2-bromo-2′-[(1*S*)-1-chloroethyl]-6′-iodo-6-[(1*Z*)-prop-1-en-1-yl]-1,1′-biphenyl
3. (1*M*)-2-bromo-2′-[(1*R*)-1-chloroethyl]-6′-iodo-6-[(1*E*)-prop-1-en-1-yl]-1,1′-biphenyl
4. (1*M*)-2-bromo-2′-[(1*S*)-1-chloroethyl]-6′-iodo-6-[(1*E*)-prop-1-en-1-yl]-1,1′-biphenyl
5. (1*P*)-2-bromo-2′-[(1*R*)-1-chloroethyl]-6′-iodo-6-[(1*Z*)-prop-1-en-1-yl]-1,1′-biphenyl
6. (1*P*)-2-bromo-2′-[(1*S*)-1-chloroethyl]-6′-iodo-6-[(1*Z*)-prop-1-en-1-yl]-1,1′-biphenyl
7. (1*P*)-2-bromo-2′-[(1*R*)-1-chloroethyl]-6′-iodo-6-[(1*E*)-prop-1-en-1-yl]-1,1′-biphenyl
8. (1*P*)-2-bromo-2′-[(1*S*)-1-chloroethyl]-6′-iodo-6-[(1*E*)-prop-1-en-1-yl]-1,1′-biphenyl